# Java/SQL - For Loop

Tags: java, sql, for-loop

Im looking to create a for loop for R[X] 
X is stated in a previous for loop

The syntax for a for loop isnt giving me any help to this at all.

r is a short for route, say it picks R1 that would correspond to a row in a database

so X can be 1,2,3 etc..

So is it possible to say For(R[X])?

CODE:

```
for(int X = 1; X < records; X++) {

                for(r[X]) {

            //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="To check if RX is in Collision Table">
           try {
               Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
               //load the oracle driver...needs to be in classes folder in jre folder
           } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
               System.out.println(
                       " Can't find class oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
               System.exit(1);
           }

           Connection conn5 = null;
           //new connection object
           Statement stmtFindRx = null;
           //new statemnt object
           ResultSet checkRx = null;
           //new record set object
           try {
               conn5 = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@oracle.staff.ittralee.ie:1521:orcl",
                       "*", "*");
               stmtFindRx = conn5.createStatement();
               // create the statement for this connection
               //</editor-fold>

                   checkRx = stmtFindRx.executeQuery(
                   "*********");
                   // get the results of select query and store in recordset object


                   while (checkRx.next()) {
                   // move to first/next record of recordset
                   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, " the answer is " + checkRx.getString(1));
                   //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, " the answer is " + fRoutes);
                   // output next record using string format
               }

               //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Error handling for Select Statement">
               checkRx.close();
               checkRx = null;
               stmtFindRx.close();
               stmtFindRx = null;
               conn5.close();
               conn5 = null;

           } catch (SQLException e) {
               System.out.println(" A SQL error: " + e.getMessage());

           } finally {
               if (checkRx != null) {
                   try {
                       checkRx.close();
                   } catch (SQLException ignore) {
                   }
               }

               if (stmtFindRx != null) {
                   try {
                       stmtFindRx.close();
                   } catch (SQLException ignore) {
                   }
               }

               if (conn5 != null) {
                   try {
                       conn5.close();
                   } catch (SQLException ignore) {
                   }
               }
           }

          // </editor-fold>


                }

           }
```

Comment: Do not load drivers or build up db connections in a loop. Do it once and reuse the connection, or use connection pooling.

Comment: Thats the plan afterwards im just doing this for now, it will be resolved later on

Comment: could you show the code that defines "r"?

Comment: Is this a syntax question? Are you asking if `for(R[X])` will compile?

Comment: i know it wont compile, it shows errors as it is, what i am asking is, is there a way to create a for loop like `for(R[X])`, And R isnt defined anywhere, but id like it to be associated with X, so i dont know if thats something that needs to be done and how?

Answer (score 0):

Taking a guess at a possible answer to the question i think you're trying to ask ...

Assuming that `R[X]` will give you some sort of collection, perhaps you might be looking for:

`foreach (Route route in R[X]) {`